# Ipad GUI Prototyping tool that runs on Windows

Tags: windows, ipad, prototyping

I'm trying to make a GUI prototype for an Ipad app but my Operating system is Windows. 
Can anyone tell what prototyping tool I should use, I don't want to use photo shop anyways

Comment: You might have more luck with this question over on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ For example, here's an existing question that might help http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/tools-for-creating-mockups-for-mobile-device-uis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com/), a very useful and easy to use protyping tool, worked for me, It provides windows,  Mac OS X, Wire Frame etc themes

Answer (score 1):

There are no such tools runs on windows. For preview your prototype design, There is a tool available on iPhone, iPad and MAC called ProtoView.

You may check it out on APP Store: http://bit.ly/protoview